# Read "time to fully charged"

Tags: battery, charging

I am testing several laptops with Windows installed and I need to write code that takes the time (in seconds or minutes) "until fully charged" - the value that windows shows, as well as the time until fully discharged.
The value that indicates how many minutes until full discharge is contained in the PowerStatus.BatteryLifeRemaining Property.

I can't find where to read the time until fully charged. I don't want to calculate it because I need exactly the same time that Windows shows.

CIM_Battery Methods, Win32_Battery, Win32_PortableBattery and PowerStatus do not provide this information.

--- BatteryStatus ---
instance of BatteryStatus
{
Active = TRUE;
ChargeRate = 717;
Charging = TRUE;
Critical = TRUE;
DischargeRate = 0;
Discharging = FALSE;
InstanceName = "ACPI\PNP0C0A\0_0";
PowerOnline = TRUE;
RemainingCapacity = 1573;
Tag = 1;
Voltage = 12543;
};

--- Win32_Battery ---
instance of Win32_Battery
{
Availability = 2;
BatteryStatus = 2;
Caption = "Internal Battery";
Chemistry = 6;
CreationClassName = "Win32_Battery";
Description = "Internal Battery";
DesignVoltage = "12543";
DeviceID = "2128SDIDell";
EstimatedChargeRemaining = 87;
EstimatedRunTime = 71582788;
Name = "Dell";
PowerManagementCapabilities = {1};
PowerManagementSupported = FALSE;
Status = "OK";
SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
SystemName = "HOME_PC";
};

--- Win32_PortableBattery ---
instance of Win32_PortableBattery
{
CapacityMultiplier = 10;
Caption = "Portable Battery";
Chemistry = 2;
CreationClassName = "Win32_PortableBattery";
Description = "Portable Battery";
DesignCapacity = 44000;
DesignVoltage = "11100";
DeviceID = "Portable Battery 0";
Location = "System Battery Bay";
Manufacturer = "SDI                 ";
MaxBatteryError = 0;
Name = "SDI                 ";
SmartBatteryVersion = "Bat123";
SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
SystemName = "HOME_PC";
};

--- BatteryStaticData ---
instance of BatteryStaticData
{
Active = TRUE;
Capabilities = 2147483648;
Chemistry = 1313818956;
CriticalBias = 0;
DefaultAlert1 = 0;
DefaultAlert2 = 179;
DesignedCapacity = 4400;
DeviceName = "Dell";
Granularity0 = "100";
Granularity1 = "18897856102400";
Granularity2 = "0";
Granularity3 = "0";
InstanceName = "ACPI\PNP0C0A\0_0";
ManufactureDate = "**************.**********";
ManufactureName = "SDI";
SerialNumber = "2128";
Tag = 1;
Technology = 0;
UniqueID = "2128SDIDell";
};

--- BatteryDesignedCapacity ---
No info returned for BatteryDesignedCapacity spacename!

--- BatteryFullChargedCapacity ---
instance of BatteryFullChargedCapacity
{
Active = TRUE;
FullChargedCapacity = 1796;
InstanceName = "ACPI\PNP0C0A\0_0";
Tag = 1;
};

--- BatteryRuntime ---
instance of BatteryRuntime
{
Active = TRUE;
EstimatedRuntime = 4294967295;
InstanceName = "ACPI\PNP0C0A\0_0";
Tag = 1;
};

--- BatteryCycleCount ---
instance of BatteryCycleCount
{
Active = TRUE;
CycleCount = 0;
InstanceName = "ACPI\PNP0C0A\0_0";
Tag = 1;
};

--- BatteryTemperature ---
No info returned for BatteryTemperature spacename!

--- MSBatteryClassEvent ---
No info returned for MSBatteryClassEvent spacename!

--- BatteryStatusChange ---
No info returned for BatteryStatusChange spacename!

--- BatteryTagChange ---
No info returned for BatteryTagChange spacename!

--- MSBatteryClass ---
instance of BatteryCycleCount
{
Active = TRUE;
CycleCount = 0;
InstanceName = "ACPI\PNP0C0A\0_0";
Tag = 1;
};

instance of BatteryRuntime
{
Active = TRUE;
EstimatedRuntime = 4294967295;
InstanceName = "ACPI\PNP0C0A\0_0";
Tag = 1;
};

instance of BatteryStaticData
{
Active = TRUE;
Capabilities = 2147483648;
Chemistry = 1313818956;
CriticalBias = 0;
DefaultAlert1 = 0;
DefaultAlert2 = 179;
DesignedCapacity = 4400;
DeviceName = "Dell";
Granularity0 = "100";
Granularity1 = "18897856102400";
Granularity2 = "0";
Granularity3 = "0";
InstanceName = "ACPI\PNP0C0A\0_0";
ManufactureDate = "**************.**********";
ManufactureName = "SDI";
SerialNumber = "2128";
Tag = 1;
Technology = 0;
UniqueID = "2128SDIDell";
};

instance of BatteryFullChargedCapacity
{
Active = TRUE;
FullChargedCapacity = 1796;
InstanceName = "ACPI\PNP0C0A\0_0";
Tag = 1;
};

instance of BatteryStatus
{
Active = TRUE;
ChargeRate = 717;
Charging = TRUE;
Critical = TRUE;
DischargeRate = 0;
Discharging = FALSE;
InstanceName = "ACPI\PNP0C0A\0_0";
PowerOnline = TRUE;
RemainingCapacity = 1573;
Tag = 1;
Voltage = 12543;
};

I can get through PowerShell the remaining discharge time in minutes ("BatteryLifeRemaining" parameter - same that Windows shows) via PowerStatus, but not the "time until fully charged" - BatteryFullLifetime parameter is always -1.

[image: see picture]

A way to get "time to fully charged" (same that windows show) via Windows PowerShell would be helpful to me.

[image: see picture]

Comment: is the web version ok? https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/11204/get-time-left-until-battery-is-fully-charged & 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BatteryManager/chargingTime or do you want BatteryLifeTime from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-system_power_status

Comment: Welcome to SU. This isn't really the site for coding advice. The coder hangout is [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21901456

Comment: It might be in here but this box doesn't have a battery so I can't test it https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-check-your-laptops-battery-health-in-windows-10

Comment: A way to get this time to fully charged via Windows PowerShell would be helpful to me.

Comment: Did you check `Win32_Battery`? It doesn't seem to be always set there for all batteries, but may be for yours https://powershell.one/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_battery

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? You mention PowerShell in a comment, but not in your question. You have not shown the choice you've tried so far. Please note that we only know what you tell us about your situation, and editing your question to improve it is always a good idea.